# PostgreSQL - Invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "foo_bar"

Tags: sql, postgresql, graphql

I'm new to PostgreSQL and trying to get this function to work. Why am I getting `invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "post_reactions"`?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema.post_current_person_has_reacted(
    post myschema.post)
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    STABLE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$

DECLARE res BOOLEAN := NULL;

BEGIN

SELECT 
myschema.post_reactions.post_id, 
myschema.post_reactions.person_id, 
myschema.post.id

FROM myschema.post_reactions pr INNER JOIN
     myschema.post p
     ON p.id = pr.post_id AND
     pr.person_id = nullif(current_setting('jwt.claims.person_id', true), '')::uuid;

   IF res IS NULL THEN
   RETURN FALSE;
   ELSE
   RETURN TRUE;
   END IF;
   
END
$BODY$;
```

**Edited** this fixes the invariant but returns the same value for all rows. i.e. if I react to one post the computed column shows TRUE for all rows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema.post_current_person_has_reacted(
    post myschema.post)
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    STABLE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$

DECLARE 
res BOOLEAN := NULL;
prpostid uuid;
prpersonid uuid;
postid uuid;

BEGIN
SELECT 
pr.post_id, 
pr.person_id, 
p.id
INTO prpostid, prpersonid, postid
FROM myschema.post_reactions pr INNER JOIN
     myschema.post p
     ON p.id = pr.post_id WHERE
     pr.person_id = nullif(current_setting('jwt.claims.person_id', true), '')::uuid;

   IF prpostid = postid and prpersonid = nullif(current_setting('jwt.claims.person_id', true), '')::uuid THEN
   res = TRUE;
   ELSE
   res = FALSE;
   END IF;
   RETURN res;
   
END
$BODY$;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the alias `pr` for it.  Try:

```
SELECT pr.post_id, pr.person_id, p.post.id
FROM myschema.post_reactions pr INNER JOIN
     myschema.post p
     ON p.id = pr.post_id AND
        pr.person_id = nullif(current_setting('jwt.claims.person_id', true), '')::uuid;
```

Once you assign the alias, you cannot use the original table name.  Or -- more accurately -- the default alias for a table is the table name and only the alias is used to reference columns throughout the query.

Comment: Thank you kindly. That gets rid of the invalid reference error but now I get `query has no destination for result data`. Am I assigning the BOOLEAN wrong? I basically want this to be a compute column (bool) for if the auth'd user has reacted to a post.

Comment: @KirkRoss . . . You can use `into` to put the values into variables: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW.

Comment: I tried adding `INTO res;` after the uuid; line but, honestly, this code is an amalgam of things I've found and I'm not sure where to put the INTO so the `res` BOOLEAN represents whether the ON ... AND comparisons are both true or false; i.e. `(post_id === post_reaction.post_id && post_reaction.person_id === jwt.claims.person_id)`.